# Sending selected option value to email with php

Tags: php, forms, email, select, submit

I want the customer to pick different options from a dropdown, and then display the selected option in an email after they have submitted a form. It is supposed to send an email to me and the customer. Right now it's not sending the value from the select.

I have the following code:

```
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $to = "myemail@myemail.com"; // this is your Email address
            $from = $_POST['email_address']; // this is the sender's Email address
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone_no'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $select = $_POST['select'];
            $subject = "Write the subject here";
            $subject2 = "Write the subject here";
            $message = "You have selected:" . "\n\n" . "" . $phone . $_POST['quantity'] . $_POST['select'] . $_POST['address_street'];
            $message2 = "you have selected:" . "\n\n" . "" . $_POST['quantity'] . $_POST['select'] . $_POST['address_street'];

            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
            echo "Din mail er sendt " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . ". Du har valgt følgende vinduer: " . $select;
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 medium-6 small-12 columns">
            <img class="windows" src="http://spejlblank.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/SPEJLBLANK_INTERIOR_V036_ENKELTFAG.jpg" width="385" height="385" alt="">
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                <select id="select" name="select">
                    <option value="" selected>VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option> 
                    <option value="30">INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG</option>
                    <option value="60">UDVENDIG</option>
                    <option value="90">INDVENDIG</option>
                    <option value="90">FORSATS (INKL. INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="quantity-field">
                <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK.">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row contact-form-pris">
            <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Indtast dine oplysninger og modtag dit uforpligtende tilbud!</h3>
            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <label for="first_name">Fornavn *</label>
                <input class="" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <label for="last_name">Efternavn *</label>
                <input class="" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <label for="address_street">Adresse *</label>
                <input class="" name="address_street" id="address_street" type="text" required/>    
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <label for="email_address">Email *</label>
                <input class="" name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <label for="mobile_no">Telefon *</label>
                <input class="" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" type="tel" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="MODTAG UFORPLIGTENDE TILBUD" class="submit-pris">
            </div>
       </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Do you realize you have an unclosed `<div>`tag ? The ` <div class="row">` it not closed, I've reindented your code so you can see it

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was just a mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your drop down

```
<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE" selected>VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option> 
    <option value="INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG">INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG</option>
    <option value="UDVENDIG">UDVENDIG</option>
    <option value="INDVENDIG">INDVENDIG</option>
    <option value="FORSATS (INKL. INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG)">FORSATS (INKL. INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG)</option>
</select>
```

In your first option you were sending blank value and other values were numbers which you probably don't want to show to make email meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<option value="" selected>VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option>
```

**to**

```
<option value="" >VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that!

But my main problem is, that it will not show the $select or $quantity when I submit